# Convert seconds to ISO8601 duration in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker, iso8601

How to convert seconds to [ISO 8601 Duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) in Freemarker?

For eg. **140 seconds -> PT2M20S**

Is there any freemarker builtins that can come in handy here? Or String manipulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding this function:

```
<#function convertDurationSeconds seconds>
    <#local mins = (seconds/60)?int />
    <#local seconds = (seconds%60) />
    <#return 'PT' + (mins > 0)?then(mins + 'M','') + (seconds > 0)?then(seconds + 'S','') />
</#function>
```

Note: I needed it for min and seconds only since it was for short video durations, this function can be extended to represent other time intervals (Y, M(month), W, D, M, and S)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't (as of 2.3.28). You will have to write a `#function` or Java methods or `TemplateMethodModelEx` for it. (BTW, I believe it would `PT2M20S`.)